# Meaning of two comparisons when talking about arrays

Tags: c++, algorithm

This is the exact question from the website.

Given a sorted array having 10 elements which contains 6 different numbers in which only 1 number is repeated five times. Your task is to find the duplicate number using two comparisons only.

I am not sure what "two comparisons" means here. Could you please shed some light on it. Thank you.

Following is my code in response to this question.

```
using namespace std;

int FindDuplicate(vector<int>& nums)
{

int count = 1, marked = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++)
{       

    if (nums[i + 1] == nums[marked])
    {
        count++;

        if (count == 5)
            return nums[marked];
    }

    else
    {
        marked = i + 1;
        count = 1;
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The line `if (nums[i + 1] == nums[marked])` is a comparison. Every time that line executes, you've done another comparison. Worst case, your code does 10 comparisons.

Comment: I don't understand why some people downgrade questions. The question is might simple to them, but others may not understand it because of inexperience, language barrier or something also.

Comment: @user3386109: `i < nums.size()` is also a comparison, as is `count == 5`.  So lots of comparisons in this function.

Comment: Perhaps it can be solved in just one comparison.

Comment: Feel free for any queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here **2 comparisons mean that you only perform 2 primitive operations of comparisons.**

`if(a > b)` can be considered as 1 comparison. But

`if(a > b && c < d)` is considered as 2 comparisons.

`if(a > b)` when executed 2 times is also 2 comparisons.

Now since **array is sorted** and there are only **6 distinct elements**:

We can easily list the various possibilites of array elements and come to the conclusion that:

The element at **index 5** when its equal to:

Element at **index 6**, the answer in this case is **element at index 6**

**Otherwise**

The **element at index 4** is the answer.

So the **solution** is:

```
if(array[5] == array[6])
 return array[5];
else return array[4];
```

Comment: It should be noted that this choice is not unique, for example one can also do `return (array[3] == array[4])? array[3]: array[8];`

Answer (score 2):

"Two comparisons" means you can only compare twice. For example, a legal solution with two comparisons would be:

- Compare the first number with the second (first comparison)

  - If the first is larger than the second, compare the first with the third (second comparison).

    - If the first is still larger, the first is the solution (no comparison)
    - If the first is not larger, the third is the solution (no comparison)
  - If the first is not larger than the second, compare the second with the fourth (second comparison)

etc...

Note that this is probably *not* the solution to the question at hand, just an example for what "two comparisons" means.

Answer (score 2):

Comparisons are operations like `==` or `<`.  "Two comparisons" means your program is only allowed to do that sort of thing twice against numbers in the array.

Without this restriction, you could just loop through the array and compare every number against the one before it.  That would definitely find the duplicate number, but it could require lots of comparisons if the duplicate is near the end of the array.  Limiting the algorithm to two comparisons means you have to come up with something more clever.

Answer (score 1):

Two comparison means the overall comparison should be two only when you get the answer. The program you have written is doing multiple comparisons because for each iteration of loop you are doing two (one in for, and other in if) comparison and in worst case this loop will iterate for 10 time i.e. size of your array.

The duplicate element can be easily obtained in just one comparison if you look at the pattern here.Suppose the six different numbers are 1 to 6. Now lets try to make each element repeating 5 times then we will get

```
    1 repeating => 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 6
    2 repeating => 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 4 5 6
    3 repeating => 1 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 5 6
    4 repeating => 1 2 3 4 4 4 4 4 5 6
    5 repeating => 1 2 3 4 5 5 5 5 5 6
    6 repeating => 1 2 3 4 5 6 6 6 6 6
```

In the above cases if you analyze then apart from the last case, nums[4] (indexing from 0) is always repeating element.
So all you need to do is

```
if(nums[5] == nums[6])
   return nums[5];
else 
   return nums[4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Two comparisons means any case where values are compared, so you can't use for loop.

To solve this puzzle note that in fact there are only 6 possible data inputs which are not trivially equivalent:

```
1: 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5
2: 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 4 5
3: 0 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 4 5
4: 0 1 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 5
5: 0 1 2 3 4 4 4 4 4 5
6: 0 1 2 3 4 5 5 5 5 5
```

So now question is how to use this in optimal way? If you compare numbers in middle you and they are equal you can answer immediately for cases 2-5.
Second comparison is to distinguish case 1 and 6.
So problem is quite simple:

```
if (tab[4] == tab[5])
    return tab[4];
else if (tab[0] == tab[1))
    return tab[0];
else
    return tab[9];
```